# Formula sum two columns for a range of rows them repeat

Tags: excel

I have a problem where i need to sum two columns for a range of values in Column A and then output the result in a specific cell. i.e. Add Columns B & C together for Phase 1 then do the same for Phase 2 etc. The attached file shows what i need. [Sample of what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3SBn.png)

I can use a simple formula to sum the content of of the two columns into the output cell for a selected range but what i really need is to be able to do this automatically when the number of rows in each range changes

Comment: Put the following formula in `G4`: `=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$23,$A$2:$A$23,$F4)+SUMIFS($C$2:$C$23,$A$2:$A$23,$F4)`

Comment: Thanks that works a treat i can change the the values to suit the other options and increase the range to what i will be using. I like it when you look at the answer and it all makes sense and feel ashamed that i couldn't have worked that out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you only have one IF so SUMIFS is not required *(Will save processing power)*:

```
  =SUMIF(A:A,F4,B:B)+SUMIF(A:A,F4,C:C)
```

Then ensure to check **Formula Tab - Calculate Options - Automatic**

Comment: Thanks that works and is easy to change for the other output locations and it should give me what i need for other options i am thinking about.